# Nginx active session counter + keeping HTTP sessions alive with python

Tags: python, http, nginx, load-balancing

I need to do some analysis over different http load balancing methods. As for now I use only Nginx solutions since they are very easy to implement (round robin, weighted RR, least conn.). In order to accomplish this I would need to create a lot of http sessions (http requests generator). I use this simple script for that:

```
 import urllib2

 while True:
      response = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.1.101')
      #below just to see if it worked
      html = response.read()
      print html
```

In a 'default' file in a 'sites-available' folder I included a following part:

```
location /nginx_status {
    # Turn on stats
    stub_status on;
    access_log   on;
    # only allow access from 192.168.1.5 #
    #allow 192.168.1.5;
    allow all;
            }
```

Thanks to that I can see such a report:

```
Active connections: 2 
server accepts handled requests
 6 6 16 
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 1
```

Here is where my questions arise:

1. What does 'active connections' mean exactly? It's based on session ID, IP of the client...?
2. When I open my site from within my script does it create a seperate session every time urllib2.urlopen() is invoked?
3. How can I manually close the connection (if it's not closed by itself somehow)?
4. Is there any way the script to move faster because for now it creates ~2 http requests per second (I commented out the print statement)?

I'm open to any suggestion. Maybe I simply use a wrong method to achieve that, I don't know...

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Tomek